# ProtocolException: Invalid header: :: std_case: HASH(0x7ff022faf630) - header starting with colon

Tags: java, apache, http-headers

I'm having a problem with response headers:

```
org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: :: std_case: HASH(0x7ff022faf630)
```

This is on calling a booking.com URL.  E.g.
http://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/the-rothley-court.html?aid=374908

Again, the problem is in the org.apache.http.message.BufferedHeader where the buffer is

> :: std_case: HASH(0x7ff022faf630)

This starts with the colon that causes all the problems!

I'm using httpcore-4.4.6 (latest on Maven)
The offending code in BufferedHeader is:

```
    public BufferedHeader(CharArrayBuffer buffer) throws ParseException {
    Args.notNull(buffer, "Char array buffer");
    int colon = buffer.indexOf(58);
    if(colon == -1) {
        throw new ParseException("Invalid header: " + buffer.toString());
    } else {
        String s = buffer.substringTrimmed(0, colon);
        if(s.length() == 0) {
            throw new ParseException("Invalid header: " + buffer.toString());
        } else {
            this.buffer = buffer;
            this.name = s;
            this.valuePos = colon + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone found a work around for this yet?

Comment: Have exact the same problem with booking.com urls using .NET HttpClient. I got away by setting useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true". Seems to be caused by a bug in libwww-perl. Tried to contact someone from booking.com but got no response.

Comment: Facing same situation, looking for a Java solution on this. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've managed to raise this with Booking.com
I'll let you know when I get a response

Comment: seems to be fixed now